# Point an iterator to an object Java?

Tags: java, iterator

I'm having a bit of trouble working this out, it may be because I last did this sort of stuff in C++ and it's slightly different but I'm having the following problem.

I'm having to write a custom ArrayList class and an associated Iterator. I have implemented the basic class structure which looks like the following:

```
public class MyArrayList<T> implements Iterable<T> {

protected T[] array;
private MyIterator<T> itr = new MyIterator<T>();

public MyArrayList() {
    array = (T[]) new Object[10];
}

public MyArrayList(int i) {
    array = (T[]) new Object[i];
}

@Override
public Iterator<T> iterator() {
    return itr;
}

private class MyIterator<T> implements Iterator<T> {

    @Override
    public void remove() {

    }

    @Override
    public T next() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

}

Obviously I'm still adding code but I've just implemented what needs to be there for now to get rid of all the error messages. What I'm attempting to do now is link my iterator called itr to the first element in the array in my list constructor.

Like in C++ with pointers do I need to point the iterator to the first item in my collection, the whole idea of an iterator is that it knows it's current position but I'm not sure if I have to explicitly tell it where to start? Hope this makes sense thanks.

Comment: Note: You should be creating a new instance of `MyIterator<T>` each time `iterator();` is called.

Comment: Sure.  Your `MyIterator` class will need a field (presumably an `int`) that tells it which element to return next.  This will need to start at zero.  But as Josh says, create your iterator in the `iterator()` method, rather than having it as a field of `MyArrayList`.

Comment: So I would need to call it like below then if I need to use it in a helper method in my list class?

`TheArrayListIterator<T> itr = iterator();` The iterator method now returns a new instance of an iterator every time it's called.

EDIT: Beat me too it, thanks!

Comment: @gRnt You keep changing your comment so it's hard to answer.  But I do think it's best to create a new iterator every time you want to iterate.  If you have just one iterator per array, you will run into problems if a method that is looping over the array calls another method that also wants to loop over the same array.

Comment: Sorry it's because I keep trying to get inline code formatting working and I always break it, in an attempt to have well written comments that make sense I try to fix it up and keep breaking it, will avoid using too much code in future, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to declare the `MyIterator` class *inside* `MyArrayList`.  The effect is that when an instance of `MyIterator` is created, it will be *associated* with an instance of the `MyArrayList` class, and it will be able to access the members of the `MyArrayList` (including the private members).  That way, your iterator will be able to access `array` and whatever variable you define for the current length.

As Josh said, instead of declaring an `itr` variable, `iterator()` should use `new MyIterator`.  The new `MyIterator` object will automatically be associated with the same `MyArrayList` object that's calling `new MyIterator` (there's a syntax for associating it with a different `MyArrayList` but you won't need it here, I think).  Inside `MyIterator`, the methods will be able to access `array` and other `MyArrayList` fields.  The constructor for `MyIterator` will be responsible for whatever initialization is needed; you'll probably want a "current index" field of some sort in `MyIterator`, and the constructor will initialize it.

More on nested classes: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html .